# Intercepting Microsoft Exchange Mail Send Events

Tags: c#, .net, events, email, exchange-server

Are there any examples which show how to hook into an Exchange mail send event?

I would like to

1. Add marketing information to all emails sent through our Exchange server when they are going to an external address.
2. Start a workflow when emails are sent

I know I could use transport rules to complete the first request, however this would need be implemented using .NET 3.5/4.0 and C# as it requires a custom GUI.

Comment: Have you looked at [Exchange Server 2007 Development](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124516%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks John, very useful. I am having a look at the EWS services, but can't seem to find an event for message sent... I will keep on looking!

Comment: Hi , Its maybe too late , but did u figure out something.

Comment: Just for anyone wondering. you could use Exchange Transport agent